# How to adjust the opacity of CSS background image instead of radio button with an icon overlay

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, radio-button, opacity

I need advice with a code I am writing in CSS.

Basically, I am replacing/hiding three radio buttons with background images. When one of the images is selected a `check` icon appears on top of it. I used parts of this code [here](http://codepen.io/teefars/pen/qOZpZL?editors=110) to make this happen.

Code works ok, except one little thing - I want to reduce the opacity of the background image once the `check` icon appears on top of it, without reducing the opacity of the `check` icon in the same time.  So far I have not been able to achieve that so need some expert advice.

HTML HERE:

```
<div class="radio-check-switch">    

    <div class="form-item">
        <label for="farm_type_agri">
            <input type="radio" name="farm_type" id="farm_type_agri" value="One"/>
            <div class="radio-switch-state" style="background-image:url('http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-400-400-10.jpg');">
                <span class="icon-on"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="radio_lbl">One</div>
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-item">
        <label for="farm_type_fore">
            <input type="radio" name="farm_type" id="farm_type_fore" value="Two"/>
            <div class="radio-switch-state" style="background-image:url('http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-400-400-10.jpg');">
                <span class="icon-on"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="radio_lbl">Two</div>
        </label>
    </div>       

</div>
```

CSS HERE:

```
.form-item{
    display:inline-block;
}
.radio-check-switch{
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.radio-check-switch input[type="radio"]{
    display: none;
}
.radio-check-switch .radio-switch-state{
    background-color:#FFF;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius:3px;
    color:#fff;
    transition:all .5s ease;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    width:120px;
    height:70px;
    position: relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    vertical-align:middle;
    /*overflow:hidden;*/
}
.radio-check-switch .radio-switch-state .icon-on,
.radio-check-switch .radio-switch-state .icon-off{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
        top:0;
}
.radio-check-switch .radio-switch-state .icon-on:after,
.radio-check-switch .radio-switch-state .icon-off:after{
    font-family:"FontAwesome";
    width:100%;
    display: block;
    line-height:50px;
    position: absolute;
    transition:all .5s ease;
}
.radio-check-switch .radio-switch-state .icon-on:after{
    content: "\f00c";
    margin-left:100;
    left:100%;
}

.radio-check-switch .radio-switch-state:hover{
    background-color:#FFEAC1;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.radio-check-switch input[type="radio"]:checked + .radio-switch-state .icon-on:after{
    content: "\f00c";
    margin-left:100;
    left:0;
    font-size:2em;
    color:#F90;
    opacity:0.4;

}
```

[JSFIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Bradg/dunz1tjs/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an `after` `pseudo-element` and then give it a background image

```css
.form-item{
 display:inline-block;
}
.radio-check-switch{
 margin-bottom:10px;
}
.radio-check-switch input[type="radio"]{
 display: none;
}
.radio-check-switch .radio-switch-state{
    position:relative;
 background-color:#FFF;
 display: inline-block;
 border-radius:3px;
 color:#fff;
 transition:all .5s ease;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 width:120px;
 height:70px;
 position: relative;
 overflow:hidden;
 vertical-align:middle;
 /*overflow:hidden;*/
}

.radio-switch-state:after{
    position:absolute;
    content:"";
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background-image:url('http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-400-400-10.jpg');
    z-index:1
}
.radio-check-switch .radio-switch-state .icon-on,
.radio-check-switch .radio-switch-state .icon-off{
 display: inline-block;
 text-align:center;
 position: absolute;
 width:100%;
 top:0;
}
.radio-check-switch input[type="radio"]:checked + .radio-switch-state:after{
    opacity:.5;
}

.radio-check-switch .radio-switch-state .icon-on:after,
.radio-check-switch .radio-switch-state .icon-off:after{
 font-family:"FontAwesome";
 width:100%;
 display: block;
 line-height:50px;
 position: absolute;
 transition:all .5s ease;
}
.radio-check-switch .radio-switch-state .icon-on:after{
 content: "\f00c";
 margin-left:100;
 left:100%;
    z-index:2;
}
    
.radio-check-switch .radio-switch-state:hover{
 background-color:#FFEAC1;
 cursor:pointer;
}
   
.radio-check-switch input[type="radio"]:checked + .radio-switch-state .icon-on:after{
 content: "\f00c";
 margin-left:100;
 left:0;
 font-size:2em;
 color:#F90;
 opacity:0.4;
     
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="radio-check-switch"> 
          
 <div class="form-item">
  <label for="farm_type_agri">
   <input type="radio" name="farm_type" id="farm_type_agri" value="One"/>
   <div class="radio-switch-state" >
    <span class="icon-on"></span>
   </div>
            <div class="radio_lbl">One</div>
  </label>
 </div>
 
    <div class="form-item">
  <label for="farm_type_fore">
   <input type="radio" name="farm_type" id="farm_type_fore" value="Two"/>
   <div class="radio-switch-state" >
    <span class="icon-on"></span>
   </div>
            <div class="radio_lbl">Two</div>
  </label>
 </div>
 
    <div class="form-item">
  <label for="farm_type_grou" >
   <input type="radio" name="farm_type" id="farm_type_grou" value="Three"/>
   <div class="radio-switch-state" >
    <span class="icon-on"></span>
   </div>
         <div class="radio_lbl">Three</div>
  </label>
 </div>
                    
                
</div>
```